# A list with no labels and no indentation

Tags: lists, indentation

I'm trying to have a list with no labels and no indentation - aligned at the same left margin as the preceding text. Why doesn't this work? :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent No indentation --- before the \verb|list|.
\begin{list}{}{}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{list}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works if you set the length parameters within the second argument of `\begin{list}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent No indentation --- before the \verb|list|.
\begin{list}{}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
}
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{list}
\end{document}
```

You may also use a `trivlist` environment. Quoting Lamport, *LaTeX: A document preparation system*, p. 115:

> The `trivlist` environment is a restricted form of the `list`
>   environment in which margins are not indented and an `\item` command
>   with no optional argument produces no text. The environment has no
>   arguments and is very  much like a `list` environment whose second
>   argument sets `\leftmargin`, `\rightmargin`, `\labelwidth`, and
>   `\itemindent` to a length of zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent No indentation --- before the \verb|list|.
\begin{trivlist}
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{trivlist}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a supplement to lockstep's answer.

When you perform the length modifications, the list parameters are already set up using the TeX `\parshape` primitive. For shaping properties, you need to use the second argument in `\begin{list}{#1}{#2}` since it is inserted before setting the `list` shape:

```
\def\list#1#2{%
  \ifnum \@listdepth >5\relax
    \@toodeep
  \else
    \global\advance\@listdepth\@ne
  \fi
  \rightmargin\z@
  \listparindent\z@
  \itemindent\z@
  \csname @list\romannumeral\the\@listdepth\endcsname
  \def\@itemlabel{#1}%
  \let\makelabel\@mklab
  \@nmbrlistfalse
  #2\relax %                       <---- #2 is inserted here
  \@trivlist
  \parskip\parsep
  \parindent\listparindent
  \advance\linewidth -\rightmargin
  \advance\linewidth -\leftmargin
  \advance\@totalleftmargin \leftmargin
  \parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth % <---- this sets the paragraph shape
  \ignorespaces}
```

Knowing the `list` has an indent of `\@totalleftmargin`, which is `\advance`d by `\leftmargin`, it also works to set `\@totalleftmargin` to `-\leftmargin`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\noindent No indentation --- before the \verb|list|.
\begin{list}{}{}
  \makeatletter
  \setlength{\leftskip}{-\@totalleftmargin}
  \makeatother
  \item \lipsum[2]
  \item \lipsum[1]
\end{list}
\end{document}​
```